# How can I load a fixture in PostgreSQL without "RI_ConstraintTrigger" error and without granting additional privileges?

Tags: postgresql, yii, yii2, fixtures

I'm using Yii 2.0.6 and when I try to load a fixture

```
php yii fixture/load Client
```

I get this error:

> Exception 'yii\db\Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE: Insufficient privilege: 7 ERROR:  permission denied: "RI_ConstraintTrigger_..." is a system trigger

After some reading I get with [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/39904-getting-insufficient-privilege-7-error/) and [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11135-postgres-fixtures-bug-ri-constrainttrigger/) for Yii 1.
They recommend not giving additional privileges but disable the transaction constraints for the fixture inserts.

Is there any way to solve this in Yii2, without granting more privileges to the application user?

Comment: I don't know Yii, but I'd imagine the same fix would work, i.e. replace the [`checkIntegrity(false)` call](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=checkIntegrity) with a `SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED` statement.

Comment: The real question is: why does your script try to drop a system constraint? You should change the script to only drop user owned constraints.

Comment: It's not my script. I'm using Yii2 fixtures command